# Check for numeric value or range

Tags: javascript, regex

A input-field could have values like:

```
23
23-45
```

No I want to correct the value:

```
string.replace(/[^\d-]/g,'');
```

But that doesn't correct these values:

```
-45
23-
45-23
10-110
```

All these values are incorrect (The valid values are from 0-100 (as they are percentage values), so 110 is unvalid). So for that cases I want the user to have a second look at the input field...

I guess I have to create a second RegEx for these unvalid cases, right?

Comment: sorry i don't know what are you trying to achieve..

Comment: If the user types '23-2' there would lead to problems, cause the user made a mistake. So I want to show the user, that there is a mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function to return true if a percentage is represented by whole numbers, where if a dash is included the first number is less than the second, and both numbers are between 0 and 100:

```
function isValidPercentage(input) {
    var mat = /^(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/.exec(input + "");
    if (mat !== null && ((mat[2] === undefined && mat[1] < 101) || (mat[1] < mat[2] && mat[2] < 101))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit#1: To force the false return if either number is greater than 100

Edit#2: Fixed errors, cleaned up the code a bit

Comment: What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/vcuopamc/ I'm always getting 'false'...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an input (#perc) and a button (#calc), then try:

```
document.querySelector('#calc').addEventListener('click', calculate);

function calculate() {
  // replace all non numeric values in the input with nothing
  // and convert it to a Number (using the + operator).
  var value = +(document.querySelector('#perc').value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
  // now you can check the value
  alert( !isNaN(value) && value >= 0 && value <= 100 
            ? 'ok ' + value 
            : 'not ok ' + value );
}
```

The SO-inline code inserter is not working, so you'll have to try it out yourself.